# How to determine arguments order's added via .bind()

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

Preface, I am using BlueBird to rewrite code from callbacks to Promises (Bluebird is awesome BTW) and I am trying to refactor my code:

I have a function that will be used in different situation, this one:

```
var getPackagesWithIndex = function(request, indexName, indexValue){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    Package.query(indexValue).usingIndex(indexName).exec(
      function(err, data){
        if (err) return reject(err);
        // Add the request to the payload
        data.request_ota = request;
        resolve(data);
    });
  })
}
```

I am chaining functions like this to get a desired result:

```
var promote = function(request){
  var destination_build = request.params.destination_build;
  return sanitizeInput(request
    ).then(getPackagesWithIndex.bind(undefined, destination_build, 'destination_build')
    ).then(preparePackages
    ).mapSeries(updatePackage)
}
```

when i `console.log` the result, the order of the arguments seems messed up:
`request` got the value of `indexValue`, is there a way of keeping things ordered ?

Comment: getPackagesWithIndex will be called with `request == request.params.destination_build`, `indexName == 'destination_build'` and `indexValue == resolved value of promise` returned in `sanitizeInput` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument to the [`bind` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) (which has nothing to do with Bluebird, btw) is the `this` value for the function call. Arguments are staying ordered though.

So when you use `getPackagesWithIndex.bind(undefined, destination_build, 'destination_build')` as a `then` callback, then `getPackagesWithIndex` will be eventually called with

- a `this` context of `undefined`
- a `request` of `destination_build`
- an `indexName` of `'destination_build'`
- and an `indexValue` with the promise result

If this is just shifted, add something like `null` in the front; if you want an altogher different order you'd better go with a function expression that contains an explicit call.

Comment: Yes, i know that the first argument is this, I guess i didn't figure out that the bindded argument was added at the end and not at the beginning, thank you Bergi and @Jaromanda-X. Yes i ended up doing some thing like: `.then(function(request){
      // Data already cleaned
      var destination_build = request.params.destination_build;
      return getPackagesWithIndex(request, 'destination_build', destination_build)
    })`